# Query outputting more rows than it should do, why is this?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a form which when it is submitted, it will output the data inputted into the form and output it in the query result. If a textbox is empty it searches all the data for that particular field. At the moment my query is outputting this:

```
SessionId     ModuleId     CourseId   ClassId    StudentUsername  TeacherUsername   Grade
ABB           CHT2520      INFO101    104        u0867587         m.prigmore        A
ABB           CHI2550      INFO101    101        u0867587         j.lu              A
ABB           CHI2550      INFO101    104        u1231231         j.lu              F
ABB           CHT2520      INFO101    101        u1231231         m.prigmore        F
NVK           CHI2550      INFO101    101        u0867587         j.lu              F
RMI           CHI2565      INFO101    102        u0660663         j.forden          F
```

It is outputting more rows then it should do. One student belongs in one class for one module. The problem is that it is showing that one student belongs in two classes for one module which is incorrect. The reason it is doing this is because it recognises which class a student is in depending on the module the student is taking.

So if there are two class for module 'CHI2550', any student that takes module 'CHI2550' are allocated to both classes when it should be one student is allocated to one class for one module and that should be determined by the 'StudentClass' table. Problem is that if I include 'StudentClass' in one of the JOINS then the query outputs 9 rows.

The query should of outputted this:

```
  SessionId     ModuleId     CourseId   ClassId    StudentUsername  TeacherUsername   Grade
    ABB           CHI2550      INFO101    101        u0867587         j.lu              A
    ABB           CHI2550      INFO101    104        u1231231         j.lu              F
    NVK           CHT2520      INFO101    103        u0867587         m.prigmore        F
    RMI           CHI2565      INFO101    102        u0660663         j.forden          F
```

How can I get the query to output the result above? Below is the query:

```
 SELECT * FROM Course c
            INNER JOIN CourseModule cm ON c.CourseId = cm.CourseId
            JOIN Module m ON cm.ModuleId = m.ModuleId
            JOIN Class cl ON m.ModuleId = cl.ModuleId 
            JOIN Teacher t ON cl.TeacherId = t.TeacherId 
            JOIN Session s ON m.ModuleId = s.ModuleId
            JOIN Grade_Report gr ON s.SessionId = gr.SessionId
            JOIN Student st ON gr.StudentId = st.StudentId
          WHERE
            ('".mysql_real_escape_string($sessionid)."' = '' OR gr.SessionId = '".mysql_real_escape_string($sessionid)."')
          AND
            ('".mysql_real_escape_string($moduleid)."' = '' OR s.ModuleId = '".mysql_real_escape_string($moduleid)."')
          AND
            ('".mysql_real_escape_string($courseid)."' = '' OR c.CourseId = '".mysql_real_escape_string($courseid)."')
          AND
            ('".mysql_real_escape_string($classid)."' = '' OR cl.ClassId = '".mysql_real_escape_string($classid)."')
          AND
            ('".mysql_real_escape_string($teacherid)."' = '' OR t.TeacherUsername = '".mysql_real_escape_string($teacherid)."')
          AND
            ('".mysql_real_escape_string($studentid)."' = '' OR st.StudentUsername = '".mysql_real_escape_string($studentid)."')
          AND
            ('".mysql_real_escape_string($year)."' = '' OR st.Year = '".mysql_real_escape_string($year)."')
          AND
            ('".mysql_real_escape_string($grade)."' = '' OR gr.Grade = '".mysql_real_escape_string($grade)."')
```

Below are each table and their data (most important tables for the problem I am facing are StudentClass, Class, Student, Module):

```
Course Table:

CourseId            CourseName                                          Duration 
INFO101         Bsc Information Communication Technology (ICT)          3/4

CourseModule Table:

CourseId      ModuleId
INFO101       CHI2550
INFO101       CHI2565
INFO101       CHT2520

Module Table:

ModuleId            ModuleName                                 Credits
CHT2520          Advanced Web Programming                       20
CHI2565          E-Commerce Business and Technology             20
CHI2550          Modern Database Applications                   20

Session Table:

SessionId   ModuleId   Semester   SessionDate   SessionTime   TeacherId  Room     Building

NVQ        CHT2520      Spring    2011-03-21    13:00:00      T2       CW2/04   Canalside West
NVK        CHT2520      Fall      2011-11-10    10:00:00      T2       CW2/04   Canalside West
RMI        CHI2565      Fall      2011-09-13    12:00:00      T5       CW5/01   Canalside West
RMT        CHI2565      Spring    2011-03-29    14:00:00      T2       CW2/04   Canalside West
ABB        CHI2550      Spring    2011-03-15    12:00:00      T1       CW4/10   Canalside West
ABH        CHI2550      Summer    2011-05-03    15:00:00      T4       CW4/10   Canalside West

Grade_Report Table:

StudentId  SessionId  Grade  Mark 
S1          NVK         F      5
S2          ABB         A      80
S1          ABB         A      80
S3          RMI         F      0

 Student Table:

StudentId  StudentForename     StudentSurname    Year   StudentUsername    CourseId 
S1         Mayur                 Patel            3       u0867587          INFO101
S2         Jim                   Carlton          3       u1231231          INFO101
S3         Ahmed                 Seedat           3       u0660663          INFO101
S4         Amar                  Barot            3       u0954857          INFO101
S5         Richard               Davies           3       u0877223          INFO101

StudentClass Table:

ClassId  StudentId
101        S1
102        S3
103        S1
104        S2


    Class Table:

ClassId    Room      ClassDay      ClassTime      ModuleId      CourseId      TeacherId 
101        CW4/10    Thursday       10:00:00      CHI2550       INFO101         T1
102        CW5/01    Wednesday      12:00:00      CHI2565       INFO101         T5
103        CW2/04    Monday         15:00:00      CHT2520       INFO101         T2
104        CW4/10    Thursday       11:00:00      CHI2550       INFO101         T1


Teacher Table:

TeacherId  TeacherForename  TeacherSurname  TeacherUsername  TeacherPassword 
T1          Joan            Lu              j.lu             scomp21
T2          Martyn          Prigmore        m.prigmore       prigmore36
T3          Arshard         Ali             a.ali            aliict
T4          Paul            Judge           p.judge          data01
T5          John            Forden          j.forden         hudds_10
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by changing the query to a single table query, and ensuring you get what you need from that, then add one table in at a time until the duplicate rows start appearing.

My best guess would be that you have one pair of tables where you need to join on two fields rather than one, and that the single field join is matching more than one row in the joined table, hence producing the extra rows in your output.

The other possibility is that you have one of your tables with duplicate row information which is causing the duplicate results.

Your `CourseModule` table may be the problem in both cases...

It's difficult to see the exact resolution from your question, well asked that it is, as there are lots of tables and many joins...